# MAUI How to use BindingPropertyChangedDelegate?

Tags: c#, xamarin, maui

I got a **BindableProperty** and I need to **do some stuff when the value changed**.
So far I got this:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty IsActiveLinkProperty =
    BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IsActiveLink), typeof(bool), typeof(LinkStackLayout), false);

public bool IsActiveLink
{
    get => (bool)GetValue(IsActiveLinkProperty);
    set => SetValue(IsActiveLinkProperty, value);
}
```

I read about using **BindingPropertyChangedDelegate** to **notify changes of my property** IsActiveLink and I'm trying to implement it. I can't get it right and I don't know how to write it that it is working. Would be lovely to get help.

My last try:
(the **error** is in the first line, "unexpected token")

```
BindableProperty.BindingPropertyChangedDelegate<bool>(BindableObject bindable, bool oldValue, bool newValue);

public static readonly BindableProperty IsActiveLinkProperty =
    BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IsActiveLink), typeof(bool), typeof(LinkStackLayout), false, BindingMode.TwoWay, propertyChanged: (b, o, n) =>
    {
        var lsl = (LinkStackLayout)b;
        lsl.DoStuff(n);
    });

public bool IsActiveLink
{
    get => (bool)GetValue(IsActiveLinkProperty);
    set => SetValue(IsActiveLinkProperty, value);
}

public void DoStuff()
{
    var icon = IsActiveLink ? CursorIconEnum.Hand : CursorIconEnum.Arrow;
    this.SetCustomCursor(icon, Handler?.MauiContext);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your code I would do like this (not tested but I assume you know more about what it is you want with it):

```cs
public static readonly BindableProperty IsActiveLinkProperty =
BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IsActiveLink), typeof(bool), typeof(LinkStackLayout), false, propertyChanged: DoStuff);

private static void DoStuff(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
{
    var linkStackLayout = (LinkStackLayout)bindable;
    var icon = (bool) newValue ? CursorIconEnum.Hand : CursorIconEnum.Arrow;
    linkStackLayout.SetCustomCursor(icon, linkStackLayout.Handler?.MauiContext);
}

public bool IsActiveLink
{
    get => (bool)GetValue(IsActiveLinkProperty);
    set => SetValue(IsActiveLinkProperty, value);
}
```